# Laplace Transform of Final integral Function

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform, integrable-systems

I want to prove that if signal $u(t)$ satisfies:

$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t u(r) \, dr=c<\infty
$$

then the Laplace Transform of the signal the following:

$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t \text{e}^{-sr}u(r) \, dr=d(s)<\infty
$$

P.S. I don't know even this conjecture is true or not.

Comment: No, this can't be true. The second integral depends on $s$.

Comment: Can you explain more or give a counter example?

Comment: Choose whatever your favorite signal is, maybe a step function. Compute the integral when $s = 1$. Then compute it when $s = 2$. They're different values.

Comment: oh, I think I should edit the question and instead of c, I should write d(s)

Comment: The dummy variable of integration shouldn't be the same as an endpoint of the integral.  Do you mean $\int_0^t u(r)\; dr$ and $\int_0^t e^{-sr} u(r)\; dr$?

Comment: Yes, thank you Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is crystal clear.

> If some function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}$ is weakly Riemann-integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$, meaning that
>   $$ \lim_{t\to +\infty} \int_{0}^{t}f(u)\,du = C<+\infty, $$
>   is it true that for any $s>0$
>   $$ (\mathcal{L} f)(s) = \lim_{t\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{t} e^{-us}f(u)\,du $$
>   is finite?

The answer is **yes** and the proof goes by integration by parts. Since the first limit is finite,
$$ M = \sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}^+}\left|\int_{0}^{t}f(u)\,du\right| $$
is finite as well. For any $s,t>0$, by denoting as $F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(u)\,du$, we have:

$$ \int_{0}^{t}e^{-su}f(u)\,du = \left[e^{-su}F(u)\right]_{0}^{t}+s\int_{0}^{t}e^{-su}F(u)\,du $$
where the absolute value of the RHS is bounded by
$$ 2M+Ms\int_{0}^{t}e^{-su}\,du \leq 2M+Ms\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-su}\,du=3M $$
no matter what the value of $t$ is. By considering the limit as $t\to +\infty$, the claim follows.

Comment: If someone remembers the proof for the Abel test for series convergence this proof should come very naturally.

Comment: How do you justify the first part of your proof? Is it true for Lebesgue integral too?

Comment: @NavidRezazadeh: $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ is actually a stronger assumption than the one I made above, the same argument works unchanged. The first part is simple: if you assume that $M=+\infty$ you contradict the finite-ness of the very first limit.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, what if we define $f(t)=\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & t \leq 0 \\
      \frac{1}{t-1} & t \in \mathcal{R}^{+}-\{1\} \\
      0 & t=1 \\
\end{array}$

Comment: @NavidRezazadeh: that is not a function in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ or an improperly Riemann-integrable function over $\mathbb{R}^+$: the initial limit is not finite, it does not even exist.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So is there a sense in which integral of $f(t)$ that I defined exists?

Comment: @NavidRezazadeh: I cannot see how. Which finite value would you like to assign to $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1-t}$ ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I cannot assign a finite value to $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)$, but is it possible to say $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt+\int_{1}^{2}f(t)dt=0$

Comment: @NavidRezazadeh: but that is not how usual integration works. $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dt}{t}$ is not zero, it does not exist. However, the principal value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of such integral is zero.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you, you've helped me a lot :)